# Cannot Hover My Div Inside The Javascript Slider

Tags: jquery, css

I have a slider that displays 4 divs and I want to hover over it. I tried adding hover on my divs but it seems that my code doesn't work. Is it because I am using a slider plugin for my image slides? Does importing js files from a plugin affect my html classes and css files too?

By the way, I am using slick.js as my carousel plugin. 
Below is my HTML structure for my divs inside the slider.
I added an `'<a>'` tag because I want my div's to be clickable.

```
            <div class="slider-program">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="program-slide">
                        <img src="images/bg/events-01.png">
                        <div class="program-section">                     
                          <span>크림슨창업특강</span>
                          <hr>
                          <p>크림슨창업특강은 고려대학교가 운영하
                            는 창업 프로젝트의 핵심 강의으로 교내
                            일반 예비 창업자를 적극적으로 발굴 및
                            육성하여 성공적인 창업과 사업화 과정
                            을 지원합니다.</p>
                          <button class="btn-more">MORE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="program-slide">
                        <img src="images/bg/events-02.png">
                        <div class="program-section">                     
                          <span>메이커스페이스특강</span>
                          <hr>
                          <p>메이커스페이스특강은 웨어러블, 사물
                            인터넷(IoT), 앱/웹, 콘텐츠, ICT 융합 등
                            지식서비스 분야의 (예비)창업자를 대상
                            으로 체험형 창업교육 및 사업화를 지원
                            하는 프로그램입니다. 
                             </p>
                          <button class="btn-more">MORE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="program-slide">
                        <img src="images/bg/events-03.png">
                        <div class="program-section">                     
                          <span>창업동아리</span>
                          <hr>
                          <p>창업동아리는 참신한 아이디어를 보유
                            한 동아리를 발굴 및 지원하며 우수한
                            동아리 창업준비공간 등을  제공하고 제
                            작을 지원합니다.</p>
                          <button class="btn-more">MORE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="program-slide">
                        <img src="images/bg/events-04.png">
                        <div class="program-section">                     
                          <span>2018년 고려대학교 크림슨컵 경진대회</span>
                          <hr>
                          <p>크림슨컵 경진대회는 고대동문과 재학
                            생의 성공 창업을 위하여 졸업생과 재학
                            생이 한팀을 이루어 공동의 창업 아이디
                            어를 사업화시키는 경진대회입니다.</p>
                          <button class="btn-more">MORE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="program-slide">
                        <img src="images/bg/events-05.png">
                        <div class="program-section">                     
                          <span>창업정규교과</span>
                          <hr>
                          <p>4차 산업혁명에 대비한 기업가
                            정신 함양 및 기술창업 핵심인
                            재 양성을 위한 창업 교과목 수
                            요를 증대하고 본교 학부생, 대
                            학원생을 대상으로 창업 준비
                            단계에 맞는 창업교육 및 지원
                            을 받을 수 있도록 창업교과목
                            체계 개편</p>
                          <button class="btn-more">MORE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="program-slide">
                        <img src="images/bg/events-06.png">
                        <div class="program-section">                     
                          <span>창업비정규교과</span>
                          <hr>
                          <p>기업가정신을 바탕으로 비즈니
                            스 역량과 기술적 역량을 모두
                            갖춘 통합적 핵심 창업인재 양
                            성을 위한 다양한 강좌와 실무
                            중심의 특강 진행</p>
                          <button class="btn-more">MORE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want each div when hovered, a red colored border will appear.

Comment: Can you share the CSS too? Maybe put it up in a jsFiddle?

Comment: please create a js fiddle link or code snippet. thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alexdeneris12/pr3k1v50/2/

Comment: the plugin doesn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alexdeneris12/pr3k1v50/6/ here-updated one @XenioGracias

Comment: posted the latest fiddle @AllanJebaraj

Comment: what plugin are you using??.. it doesn't look like a slider

Comment: I'm using slick.js. I don't know how to put plugins in jsfiddle. my apologies because this is my first time coding @XenioGracias

Comment: @Alex Deneris on the right side you paste js and css link

Comment: here @XenioGracias -> https://jsfiddle.net/alexdeneris12/pr3k1v50/8/

Comment: It seems, your code working properly, on hover over a div its worked. I checked the code `a div:hover { color: #000; background: #808080; }`

Comment: This is invalid HTML, you can not nest `button` into `a`, they are both “interactive” elements.

Answer (score 0):

This will display each div when hovered, a red colored border will appear

```
 $('.slider-program').on('mouseenter','.program-slide', function (e) {
    $(this).css("border", "red solid 1px");                                     
 });
 $('.slider-program').on('mouseleave','.program-slide', function (e) {
   $(this).css("border", "");
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Border is not defined completly (only border color)
2. Missing opening class

```css
before:
  &:hover {
   border-color: #910023!important;
  }

now:
   &:hover {
    border: 2px solid #910023!important;
   }
```

```html
before:
</head>
<div class="slider-program">

now:
</head>
<div class="program">
<div class="slider-program">
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/byxpqLm6/